# WPF Localization with LocBaml: System.IO.IOException was unhandled

Tags: wpf, locbaml

I am localizing a WPF application using LocBaml.  I have successfully created the satellite assemblies and put them in their appropriate folders.  I run the application from my box and it works great! Changing languages on the fly, etc.  The problem is, I can't run it on any other machine but mine. I can have a co-worker compile the application on their box and I can successfully run the app from my machine mapped in, but he cannot.  It is utterly perplexing.  I'm sure it's got to be something so simple I'm overlooking it.

```
System.IO.IOException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146232800
  Message=Cannot locate resource 'maincontrol.baml'.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  StackTrace:
       at MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourcePart.GetStreamCore(FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
       at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetStream(FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
       at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
       at DCG.Designer.Library.MainControl.InitializeComponent() in D:\TFS\CardWizard Software Main\Trunk\ClientInterfaces\DCG.Designer.Library\obj\Debug\MainControl.g.vb:line 628
       at DCG.Designer.Library.MainControl..ctor() in D:\TFS\CardWizard Software Main\Trunk\ClientInterfaces\DCG.Designer.Library\MainControl.xaml.vb:line 42
       at DCG.Designer.MainWindow.libWindow_LanguageChanged(Object sender, CultureInfo Language) in D:\TFS\CardWizard Software Main\Trunk\ClientInterfaces\DCG.Designer\MainWindow.xaml.vb:line 240
       at DCG.Designer.Library.MainControl.Language_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in D:\TFS\CardWizard Software Main\Trunk\ClientInterfaces\DCG.Designer.Library\MainControl.xaml.vb:line 808
       at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem.InvokeClickAfterRender(Object arg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run()
       at DCG.Designer.Application.Main() in D:\TFS\CardWizard Software Main\Trunk\ClientInterfaces\DCG.Designer\obj\Debug\Application.g.vb:line 65
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, after two days of driving myself crazy it ended up being that I just needed to sign the assemblies.  My app was signed with a unique key and therefore my localized assemblies needed to be signed as well.  Still doesn't answer the question as to why it worked on my machine unsigned, but anyways, it works now!

Got the answer here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/35d7be1b-a0bb-4388-b05f-70182f0e9018/locbaml-doesnt-work

I signed my new localized assemblies with the following:

sn.exe –R sv-SE\my.resources.dll my.snk